# InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am getting the following error :

> This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : XXXXXX.yyy.com

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
if (($ToolsStatus -eq 'toolsOk' -OR $ToolsStatus -eq 'toolsOld') -AND $VMVSSStatus -eq $null -AND $OperatingSystem -match "64-bit" ) {
            try{
                Copy-Item -Path ".\64bit\$ToolsVersion.exe" -Destination "\\$FQDN\c$\"  -Container -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop
                "File $ToolsVersion.exe copied on $vmName" | Do-Log
                try {
                    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $FQDN -ScriptBlock { 
                        Start-Process "C:\$ToolsVersion.exe" -ArgumentList '/s /v "/qn reboot=r ADDLOCAL=all"' -Wait 
                        Start-Process "C:\$ToolsVersion.exe" -ArgumentList '/s /v "/qn reboot=r REMOVE=VSS"' -Wait
                        Start-Process "C:\$ToolsVersion.exe" -ArgumentList '/s /v "/qn reboot=r ADDLOCAL=VSS"' -Wait 
                        "Installation completed on $vmName" | Do-Log
                        taskkill /IM vmtoolsd.exe /F
                        "VMtools process killed on $vmName" | Do-Log
                        Start-Service -Name VMTools
                        "VMware Tools service was started on $vmName" | Do-Log
                    } 
                }
                catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]#PSRemotingTransportException
                {
                     "Unable to install on $vmName. Following error was encountered:" +$_.Exception.GetType().FullName | Do-Log
                }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `$ToolsVersion` variable is undefined in the scope of `Invoke-Command`, since the scope is executed on the remote machine.

Try:

```
Start-Process "C:\$Using:ToolsVersion.exe" -ArgumentList '/s /v "/qn reboot=r ADDLOCAL=all"' -Wait
```

instead.

From [about_Remote_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6):

> USING LOCAL VARIABLES
>
> You can also use local variables in remote commands, but you must indicate that the variable is defined in the local session.
>
> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, you can use the Using scope modifier to identify a local variable in a remote command. ...

**UPDATE 1:**

To retrieve the logs from the remote you've to change your code to:

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $FQDN -ScriptBlock { 
                    $computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                    Start-Process "C:\$ToolsVersion.exe" -ArgumentList '/s /v "/qn reboot=r ADDLOCAL=all"' -Wait 
                    Start-Process "C:\$ToolsVersion.exe" -ArgumentList '/s /v "/qn reboot=r REMOVE=VSS"' -Wait
                    Start-Process "C:\$ToolsVersion.exe" -ArgumentList '/s /v "/qn reboot=r ADDLOCAL=VSS"' -Wait 
                    $logging =  @()
                    $logging = "$computerName: Installation completed on $vmName"
                    taskkill /IM vmtoolsd.exe /F
                    $logging += "$computerName: VMtools process killed on $vmName" 
                    Start-Service -Name VMTools
                    $logging += "$computerName: VMware Tools service was started on $vmName" 
                    $logging
                } | Do-Log
```

Here the array `$logging` will be serialized over the network. On your machine, it's deserialized, and every entry of the array is sent to your local pipeline.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm. If you see above, I am trying to call a Filter function called "Do-Log" as well inside the scriptblock but it is not being recognized. How can I make it work ?